# How can i append images (used in textures) from another blend file?

Tags: python

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(blend_file, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
                     print("*"*50)
                     for obj in data_from.objects:
                        print("obj is", obj)
                        if obj == source_obj_name:
                            data_to.objects = [obj]
                            break  
                        
                     for img in data_from.images:
                         data_to.images = [img]
                        
                     for mat in data_from.materials:
                         print("mat is", mat)
                         data_to.materials = [mat]
```

i can import materials and objects, but i don't get the images for my materials.
what am i missing here?
i see the image names so....but i don't see the images, so obviously i am making something wrong here.

this is what i can see: material + image name is there, but the image isn't there.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "you dont see"? If you inspect a material using such an image, does it has an empty image texture node?

Comment: no, there is an image texture node with the right name, but if i select the image texture node,  don't see the image in the image editor. Although the name is there. i added an image how it looks like, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: With a test scenario A.blend -> B.blend and different image paths i cant reproduce your problem. But if i disallow read access on that image, i get your exact scenario. Maybe its not Blender but OS related?

Comment: i am working on a macbook...my user has read+write permissions, but not "everyone" -> was just set to read. I just changed for everyone to read and write...and now it's getting worse: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qccvF.png even no name anymore - but anyway - you seem to be on the right track ;) that's how my rights looked before:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9t4F.png